# Duplicate pie chart data

Tags: java, android, achartengine, popupwindow, pie-chart

In my Android app I am drawing a pie chart using achartengine libraray. The chart is showing in a popup window when a button is clicked. Chart data is retrieving from the sqlite database. Here is my code.

```
btnpieChart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (distributionSeries != null || defaultRenderer != null) {
            distributionSeries.clear();
            defaultRenderer.removeSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        }

        SelectDBAdapter selectDBAdapter = SelectDBAdapter
                .getDBAdapterInstance(getActivity());
        try {
            selectDBAdapter.openDataBase();
            chartDataMap = selectDBAdapter
                    .getPieChartData(strBusinessUnit,
                            currentPeriod, currentYear);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            selectDBAdapter.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            selectDBAdapter.close();
        }
        System.out.println("chartDataMap === "+ chartDataMap);

        if (chartDataMap.size() > 0) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : chartDataMap.entrySet()) {
                lstBrandNames.add(entry.getKey());
                lstAchievedVals.add(entry.getValue());
            }

            ArrayList<Double> distribution = calc_Percentage(lstAchievedVals);
            System.out.println("distribution === " + distribution);
            lstBrandNames = set_lables(lstBrandNames, distribution);

            distributionSeries = new CategorySeries(
                    "Brands - Achievement Progress");
            for (int i = 0; i < distribution.size(); i++) {
                distributionSeries.add(lstBrandNames.get(i), distribution.get(i));
            }

            defaultRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
            defaultRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            defaultRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            defaultRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
            //defaultRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

            for (int i = 0; i < distribution.size(); i++) {

                seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                Random rnd = new Random(); 
                int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
                seriesRenderer.setColor(color);
                seriesRenderer.setGradientEnabled(false);
                seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
                seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(false);

                defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
            }

            defaultRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            defaultRenderer.setChartTitle("Brands - Achievement Progress");
            defaultRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
            defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            defaultRenderer.setShowLabels(true);

            mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(), distributionSeries, defaultRenderer);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pie_chart, null);

            PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
            layout.removeAllViews();  
            layout.addView(mChartView);

            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 50, 50);

        }
    }
});
```

The problem is when I click the button again and again chart data is duplicated pie chart data.

I think distributionSeries and defaultRenderer are not clear properly when I back from the pie chart. And also. when I back from the chart window logcat says:

```
11-26 05:15:33.163: W/InputEventReceiver(1431): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you delete the items from the series, but you don't do the same for your `lstBrandNames`, which causes the duplication of data.